# Remove double quotes from the beginning and the end of decimal numbers inside a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following string and want to remove all double quotes in front of and at the end of decimal numbers keeping other quotes.

```
"{"id":"default","values":{"level1":["0.0000","0.0000","0.0000"],"level2":["1.0000","1.0000","1.0000"], "score":"2.1100"}}"
```

should be

```
"{"id":"default","values":{"level1":[0.0000,0.0000,0.0000],"level2":[1.0000,1.0000,1.0000], "score":2.1100}}"
```

With `replace(/\"(?=[0-9]\.[0-9]+)/g, '')` I managed to to get rid of double quotes at the beginning of the numbers, but cannot figure out how to do it for quotes at the end.

Comment: You may capture expression (including end quotes) and replace with trimmed text (trimming quotes).

Comment: That looks like JSON. Wouldn't it be better if you first create an object, and then deal with it, instead of treating it as a raw string?

Comment: Are you planning on parsing that into a JS object at some point, because if you are, removing the quotes will just round the numbers down to the nearest non-zero number anyway: `0.0000` will become `0`, `1.0000` will become `1` and `2.1100` will become `2.11`.

Comment: My problem is that the server I need to send my JSON object to only accepts decimal numbers (and I cannot do anything about it). Means it expects a number 1 to be 1.0000

Comment: But it does not except them as string, it wants them to be "doubles"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace `/"(\d[.]\d+)"/g` by `$1`. `$1` refers to the first capturing group, i.e. `\d[.]\d+` (the content without the quotes). `\d` is only a shortcut for `[0-9]`.

```
> var str = '{"id":"default","values":{"level1":["0.0000","0.0000","0.0000"],"level2":["1.0000","1.0000","1.0000"], "score":"2.1100"}}';
undefined
> str.replace(/"(\d[.]\d+)"/g,"$1")
'{"id":"default","values":{"level1":[0.0000,0.0000,0.0000],"level2":[1.0000,1.0000,1.0000], "score":2.1100}}'
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about the possibility to reference the group. It works with "$1". I'll mark this as an answer because it actually does what was asked - replacing in a string

Answer (score 2):

For the mentioned string, you can parse it into a JavaScript object using `JSON.parse()` and then use `parseFloat()` on the values you need to consider as floating point numbers.

```
var str = '{"id":"default","values":{"level1":["0.0000","0.0000","0.0000"],"level2":["1.0000","1.0000","1.0000"], "score":"2.1100"}}';

str = JSON.parse(str);
str.values.level1 = str.values.level1.map(function(_item) { return parseFloat(_item); });
str.values.level2 = str.values.level2.map(function(_item) { return parseFloat(_item); });
str.values.score = parseFloat(str.values.score);

// if you need it back as a JSON string
str = JSON.stringify(str);
```

Comment: *+1*: A better alternative than a regex IMO.

Comment: My problem is that the server I need to send my JSON object to only accepts decimal numbers (and I cannot do anything about it). Means it expects a number 1 to be 1.0000. That's why I actually apply toFixed on all numbers, call JSON.stringify and now need to appear the "string numbers" without double quotes

Comment: In that case, the above output (after the final stringify) should do the job.

Comment: @Casimir et Hippolyte - Thank you for the correction. :-)

Comment: Your solution does not work in my case, because after the object is stringified all values are numbers, which in JSON could be intergers or doubles. The decimal point is lost.
    "{"id":"default","values":{"level1":[0,0,0],"level2":[1,1,1],"score":2.11}}"

Comment: @Danilla - The decimal point is lost after `parseFloat()` because there are only zeros on the RHS - For example: try `console.log(5.000);` - the output will be `5`, and not `5.000` - If you need to retain the zeros after the `.`, represent them as strings.

Comment: You are right I know how it works in JS, but as I mentioned in the comment above, the server is not following the JSON's definition of number and expects a numeric value to be always a double value. Strings are not accepted by the server, same is for "integer numbers"...

Comment: In that case, a string replacement solution (as in sp00m's answer) is definitely the best (and only) way to go.